# php how to deliver a variable value to another page?

Tags: php

I am practicing PHP and stuck with following.

there are two pages list.php and view.php and I want to make a detail page link on list.php to go to view.php

on the list.php page, I put this below.

```
<a href='view.php?num=$num'>
```

`$num` is defined to get a value of auto_incremented ID from DB.

on the view.php page, it seems it does not get `$num` value from the view.php page.
`echo($num)` gives "unidentified variable error"

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the variable from [`$_GET[]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) first.

```
$num = $_GET['num'];
echo $num;
```

It's a good idea to wrap that in the following block as well to make sure the variable is set before you use it.

```
if (isset($_GET['num']) {
    ...
}
```

This way, when you go to just `view.php`, it won't give you an error because there is no `$_GET['num']`

Comment: $_GET data should be "protected" in order to prevent a security issue on print.
With php you should use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities function to print data. http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php